# PHP UTF8 encoding issue with Special characters

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I am using PHP to connect to a database and retrieve mostly strings. These strings are sentences written in Portuguese, therefore they have plenty of "é", "ç", "ú", etc...

When retrieving I'm doing this:

```
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
$array_req = array();

while($rs = sqlsrv_fetch_object($res)){
    // Get info request
    $temp_req = array();
    $temp_req['id'] = $rs->id;
    $temp_req['title'] = utf8_decode($rs->title);
    ...
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$array_req));
```

And by doing that *utf8_decode* characters like "ç" get replaced by "?" for example. If I don't do the decoding then the text is all well since it is correctly stored on the database. However, if I don't do the decoding, the *json_encode* will retrieve the strings as *null*.

How do I keep the characters? I already tried *mb_convert_encoding*, *htmlspecialchars*, nothing seems to work.

EDIT: This script was being requested by an Android app. However I was testing on the browser and it seems if I actually encode the strings in UTF8 and send the json with the flag *JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE* sugested below, the browser still returns bad characters but the android app reads them ok. Go figure...
This is the working code:

```
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn,$query);
$array_req = array();

while($rs = sqlsrv_fetch_object($res)){
    // Get info request
    $temp_req = array();
    $temp_req['id'] = $rs->id;
    $temp_req['title'] = utf8_encode($rs->title);
    ...
}
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$array_req), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Which charset does your DB table use?

Comment: JSON is supposed to be UTF-8 so you dont need to decode it. Where are you getting NULL

Comment: See this if you haven't already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through could also be a dupe.

Comment: Is this another [UTF-8 All the way through issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: **Great minds** again @Fred-ii-

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks *lol!*

Comment: This script was being requested by an Android app. However I was testing on the browser and it seems if I actually encode the strings in UTF8 and send the json with the flag Scott C Wilson sugested below, the browser still returns bad characters but the android app reads them ok. Go figure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utf8_decode` is what is changing the characters into "?".  You shouldn't do that - just use the data as is without processing it.  Use the option `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` on json_encode and it should work.

```
json_encode(array('result'=>$str), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: But then the json_encode will retrieve them as null to whoever requests that script. I tested it...